# Create gradle file programmatically from build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have an assignment task so I have downloaded the project to implement the task
but found in readme file

> "you still need to register for an [API key](https://api.nasa.gov/)
> and add it to `app/local.gradle` - see `local.gradle.example` for
> details."

and found inside

> local.gradle.example

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"api key\""
    }
}
```

and the

> app/local.gradle

was not there

and inside build.gradle file I have found

```
if (!file("local.gradle").exists()) {
exec {
    commandLine "sh"
    args = ["-c", "cp local.gradle.example local.gradle"]
    }
}
apply from: "local.gradle"
```

when I tried to run the project it gives an error says

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "E:\android-assignment-main\app"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

so how to first create local.gradle file? from programmatically from build.gradle

Comment: Why not just copy the file by hand and change the value (I think this is what the instructions are telling you to do).  Obviously, make sure you don't check that file into Git

Comment: I think instruction wants to do  that programmatically as they include copy command in gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that you are on Windows and try to run a shell script, which will not work like this.

I would suggest to use Gradle's [Copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) to do this:

```gradle
task copyLocalGradle(type: Copy) {
    if (!file("app/local.gradle").exists()) {
        from 'local.gradle.example'
        into 'app'
        rename 'local.gradle.example', "local.gradle"
    }
}
```